# How to save image position after drag

Tags: php, jquery, css, draggable, jquery-draggable

I am new for jquery I have design a custom shape for image frame with image dragging. I am able to retrieve the values of "Top" and "Left" positions. But I am not able to store that position for the permanent after image draging. Even I don't know how it is posibble without using database. Below are my Code for `test.php`

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".headerimage").css('cursor', 'pointer');
    var y1 = $('.picturecontainer').height();
    var y2 = $('.headerimage').height();
    var x1 = $('.picturecontainer').width();
    var x2 = $('.headerimage').width();
    $(".headerimage").draggable({
        scroll: false,
        containment: "#picturecontainer",
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            document.getElementById("img_top").value = ui.position.top;
            document.getElementById("img_left").value = ui.position.left;
            if (ui.position.top >= 0)
            {
                ui.position.top = 0;
            }
            else if (ui.position.top <= y1 - y2)
            {
                ui.position.top = y1 - y2;
            }
            else if (ui.position.left <= x1 - x2)
            {
                ui.position.left = x1 - x2;
            }
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            //####
        }
    });
});
```

```
<style>
    .picturecontainer{
        overflow: hidden; 
        position: relative; 
        width: 350px; 
        height: 350px; 
        background: #d3d3d3;
        /*    border: 1px solid #888;*/
        background-size:cover;
        -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0% 60%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
        shape-outside: polygon(0% 60%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 60%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
        -webkit-shape-margin: 20px;
    }
</style>

<h2>Example 1</h2>
<div class="ui-widget-content" style="padding:10px;">
    TOP : <input type="text" name="img_top" id="img_top" value="" /><br />
    LEFT : <input type="text" name="img_left" id="img_left" value="" /><br />
    <div class="picturecontainer" style="">
        <img style="position: absolute;" class="headerimage ui-corner-all" src="img/1.jpg" />
        <br />
    </div>
    <input id="saveImage" type="button" value="Save" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do the same as in your `drag` function but than in `stop`?

Comment: @putvande didn't get you... same I have to mention in stop function or what?

Comment: I guess so. That depends on what you want to save.

Comment: @putvande I want to save the position, If I am dragging that image suppose left or right, top or bottom then after reloading the page again the new position should not change. for saving the position I want to use save button.

Comment: And how are you saving it? After clicking the 'save' button, what happens? Where is the code that actually saves the locations?

Comment: @putvande I am not saving it anywhere, That what my question is. I am not able to save it. This is the only code where I am working right now.

Comment: Well.. since you tagged PHP, you could write some PHP that saves it for you (either in DB, Session or whatever) or you could make some JavaScript that uses localStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use server-side script and the save the values into database, these two

```
document.getElementById("img_top").value = ui.position.top;
document.getElementById("img_left").value = ui.position.left;
```

will help to retrieve the values.